# UIWebView Crashing App

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4, io

This is my Code that all together crashes my app

The bit that assigns the webview its value: It works fine until the last line. When it SIGBARTS.

```
[cell setLabelText:[cellTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[cell imagesetter:[imageTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[cell desSetter:[desTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


[cell changeProductWeb:[webTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

The Array

```
webTitle = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:

            @"http://www.google.com/",
            @"http://www.google.com/",
            @"http://www.google.com/",
            @"http://www.google.com/",

            nil];
```

The action

```
- (IBAction) changeProductWeb:(NSString *)str{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
    NSMutableURLRequest *requestObj = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];        
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];

}
```

This is the only bit the crashes the program. When I remove it it wont crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to call [webView retain] at some point. You would get a SIGABART like that if your webView is not being held onto by your class.

A simple solution is to use this in your .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIWebView *webView;
```

Then in your .m file go:

```
@synthesize webView;
```

Then, wherever you refer to your webview, make sure to add "self"

```
 [self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```